# How to force CMFCPropertyGridCtrl to refresh after adding an item?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, propertygrid

I add an item to the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl, but the new item does not show up only if i click the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl.

Now i have a indirect solution to show up the new item by calling `ExpandAll()`, but i don't want to expand those i have collapsed.

Is there a way to show up the new item gracefully ?

Comment: [CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::AddProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983781.aspx) has a *bRedraw* parameter, that you need to set to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry for not explaining my question clearly. I add an item by calling [CMFCPropertyGridProperty::AddSubItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984633.aspx). Is there still a way to work like `AddProperty` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `CMFCPropertyGridProperty.AddSubItem()` call, new item will show up by the following two calls:

```
YourGridCtrl.AdjustLayout();
YourGridCtrl.RedrawWindow();
```

Hope it helps !